# Allow commas and decimal points in input field AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've come across an AngularJS filter than changes numeric values in a input field into a formatted number `i.e 2500 becomes 2,500` and when applied to the `modal` it parses as an integer.

I was wonder if it was possible to add decimal points and keep the formatting for the user so `2500.24` becomes `2,500.24`.

The script is as below:

```
angular.directive('format', function ($filter) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) {
                return;
            }

            ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function () {
                return $filter('currency')(ctrl.$modelValue, '', 2);
            });

            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[\,]/g, ''),
                    b = $filter('currency')(plainNumber, '', 2);

                elem.val(b);

                return plainNumber;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the pattern I use is:

```
<input format pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin ng-currency-mask.

https://github.com/vtex/ng-currency-mask

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['vtex.ngCurrencyMask']);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="value" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="value" currency-mask />
```